# Elasticsearch refusing connection through Python client

Tags: python, elasticsearch

While testing about with ES I'm struggling to get it to work with it's Python Client. I've followed the quick-start guide and set up local Docker containers running both ES and Kibana. To test the installation I used Postman to send some requests over to `http://localhost:9200/` which responded with proper data.

The Python Client however fails to connect - installed it via Pip, imported it and set it up like so:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(
    ['localhost'],
    scheme="http",
    port=9200,
)

if not es.ping():
    raise BaseException("Connection failed")
```

The Error being thrown:

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Here's an excerpt from my docker-compose:

```
es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.3
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
```

Note that my python-container does **not** share the network with ES - does that play a notable role here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it *was* related to the networks.

I've fixed this issue by including ES and Kibana in the same network as my Python application and changing the initialization to:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(
    ['es01'],
    scheme="http",
    port=9200,
)
if not es.ping():
    print("Connection failed")
else:
    print("Connection successful")
```

`es01` references the name of the docker container running Elasticsearch.